# Manipulate auto execution of Javascript since Burp can only see HTTP Requests/responses

Tags: javascript, burp-suite

There a javascript that is executing in my browser and it is generating session token. (This was a design requirement to the dev team Sesion token is generated on the client side - don't ask me why lol)

I want to be able to modify the javascript variables during execution (just as if I was using Debug in Netbeans for instance)

I though I'd use burp suite but it only catches request (not the building of a request by Js)

What can I do to do that ?

Also, I thought I'd use browser debugger but strangely, none of the loaded JS seems to be generating the session token. One of the JS just do that and I see it later in burp interceptor.

Any help here ?

Comment: You'll have to be clearer in your description. What do you want to be sent in the subsequent request: No session token, or a manipulated token? Do you want to replace the token creation logic with your own?

Comment: @lab9 Here's what I meant. I have two JS. A.js and B.js. In chrome, when I add a breakpoint for all xhr, I catch B.js. Good. But, inside B, there is a variable whose content is set by A.js. The problem is that I don't know the real name of A.js It could be any JS loaded (I only know B.js because chrome breakpoint on it)

Comment: You could use either Burpsuite or your browsers developer tools to search for all ocurrences of variable assignments to that variable. That way you can narrow down the seach for the session token logic.

Comment: @lab9 The probleme is that the function called is part of webpack. Therefore, there is a wrapper funtion in the regular javascript that calls that webpack function. The problem is don't know the wrapper name. I was able to find the webpack funtion by setting a breakpointon all xhr but I wished I had a chain of all mehod calls that triggered it

Comment: what if you just let the logic run as-is, but overwrite the variables according to your needs afterwards, using your own script?